# Am I crazy? Demos on jQuery's 'effects' page not working in any browser

Tags: jquery, firebug, demo

I want to make sure I'm not crazy, because I can't get any of the effects demos to work on jQuery's demo pages. I thought it might be my new Firebug version (1.5.2) or Firefox in general, but they're not working in IE or Chrome either.

Here are the links where the demos aren't working. One is for highlight, and the other is for explode. Incidentally, highlight is the one that I'm trying to use. Could it be the new jQuery UI version? Is anyone else having these not work?

[Effect 1](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/effect)
[Effect 2](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight)

Comment: Yup, looks like something is broken in there.

Comment: Firebug shows that `.effect()` is not defined... so looks like a problem with the code

Comment: Ran it through firebug, $("div").effect is not a function. Whoops!

Comment: The working jQuery UI demo is here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: Just an update to those that care, there's an active ticket on this now: http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5307

Comment: This seems to be repaired as of this date.(Except first Animate one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery-UI is not being included on the pages, so none of the effects in it work at the moment.

So no, you're not crazy, it's a glitch on their side.

Example, it's looking for: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/effects.core.js
Which is now: http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js

Looks like the doc pages haven't been updated to match this change.

Answer (score 0):

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Timestamp: Mon, 8 Mar 2010 18:56:39 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 14
Char: 7
Code: 0
URI: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/effect